# Возможно ли поменять все ссылки в теле документа после проверки адресной строки через js

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Доброго времени суток!

Только начал изучать js и интересует решение такой вот задачи.

Имеются ссылки `<a class="link" href="http://1234.ru"></a>`, при несоответствии проверяемого адреса нужно заменить ссылки. Написал такую вот функцию, но замена не происходит, в то время как редирект такого типа срабатывает

```
document.location.href="http://http://www.google.com"
```

```
function linkreplace(){
    var link = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
    var url = "http://yandex.ru";
    var regV = /yandex\.ru/gi;
    var result = url.match(regV);

    if (result) {
        console.log('1');
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName('link').href = 'http://google.com';
    }
}
linkreplace();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName
возвращает массив.
надо вот так:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('link')[0].href = 'http://google.com';
```

Если таких ссылок много, я бы сделал так

```js
function linkreplace(link){
    var url = link.href;
    var regV = /yandex\.ru/gi;
    var result = url.match(regV);
    if (result) {
        console.log(url, 'Not replaced');
    } else {
        console.log(url, 'Replaced');
        link.href = 'http://google.com';
    }
    console.log(link);
}

var links = document.getElementsByClassName('link');
for(var link of links) linkreplace(link);
```

```html
<a class='link' href='http://yandex.ru'></a>
<a class='link' href='http://google.ru'></a>
<a class='link' href='http://test.ru'></a>
```